# preventDefault and return false; if i add if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frm_registration").submit(function(event){
        var submit = false;

        termsIsChecked      = $("#user_terms_of_service").is(":checked");
        uEmail              = $("#user_email").val();
        uPassword           = $("#user_password").val();
        uConfirmPassword    = $("#user_password_confirmation").val();
        uFirstName          = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uLastName           = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uContactNumber      = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uOtherInformation   = $("#user_firstname").val();


        // if(uPassword.length === 0){
        //    uPassword.after("<p>Password can't be blank</p>");
        //    submit = false;
        // }

        if(submit === false){
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

if i uncomment the if block the form will submit event if i change `event.preventDefault();` to `return false;` it still won't work if the if block is uncommented. my problem is why jquery is reponding like this, if i add if statement the **preventDefault** and **return false;** wont work but if i remove if statement or comment it out the **preventDefault and return false; will work**.can someone explain why its like this

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: that why i wonder because there is no error.. and i even tried clearing the cache sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is uPassword is not a jQuery object, it is a string so there is no method called `after` for String object. Which should give you an error like `Uncaught TypeError: uPassword.after is not a function` in your browser console.

```
$("#user_password").after("<p>Password can't be blank</p>");
```

---

Also you will have to initialize `submit` with the value false like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#frm_registration").submit(function (event) {
        var submit = true;

        termsIsChecked = $("#user_terms_of_service").is(":checked");
        uEmail = $("#user_email").val();
        uPassword = $("#user_password").val();
        uConfirmPassword = $("#user_password_confirmation").val();
        uFirstName = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uLastName = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uContactNumber = $("#user_firstname").val();
        uOtherInformation = $("#user_firstname").val();


        if (uPassword.length === 0) {
            $("#user_password").after("<p>Password can't be blank</p>");
            submit = false;
        }

        if (submit === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8fyqw6rj/)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply sir.I over look that part